# When does Riemann-Lebesgue lemma hold in general?

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, bounded-variation

Let's say for simplicity that I'm on the torus $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. In this setting, Riemann-Lebesgue lemma could be stated as: for any $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$,
$$ \lim_{\vert k\vert\to\infty}\int_\mathbb{T} f(x)e^{ikx}\, dx =0$$
which can be interpreted as: for any $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$, $\widehat{f}\in c_0$, where $\widehat{\cdot}$ denotes the discrete Fourier transform and $c_0$ the space of infinitesimal sequences. If I considered a Radon measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{T}$ instead of $f$, then it's easy to check that $\widehat{\mu}\in l^\infty$ and Riemann-Lebesgue lemma fails, take $\mu=\delta_x$. The case $d\mu = f\,dx$ with $f\in L^1$ corresponds to measures which are absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure.

However the same technique of proof for $f\in L^1$, i.e. showing the statement for smooth functions and then exploiting a density argument, shows that Riemann-Lebesgue lemma holds for any $\mu$ belonging to the closure of smooth functions in the total variation norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{TV}$. So my question is: what is this space? Is it just the space of all absolutely continuous measures or it contains other objects (like the derivative of the Cantor function)? Does it have a proper characterization?

Comment: A measure defined by an $L^1$ density has variation equal to the $L^1$ norm. So this space is already closed. But I may not be understanding you correctly.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the closure of smooth functions will be just the measures absolutely continuous w.r.t Lebesgue, so with $L^1$ density. SIlly me, I didn't realize the answer was so simple.

Answer (score 3):

The class of measures for which the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma remains true is the well-known class of [Rajchman measures](https://rdlyons.pages.iu.edu/pdf/seventy.pdf) See [also](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/chapters/edit/10.1201/9780429332838-22/seventy-years-rajchman-measures-russell-lyons)
This class is defined as follows
$$ \mathcal R(\Bbb T)=\{\mu\in M(\Bbb T) :\widehat{\mu}(\xi)\to0, \quad|\xi|\to\infty\}.$$

Noet that identifying $L^1(\Bbb T)\equiv \{\mu=|f|d x: f\in L^1(\Bbb T)\}$ we have

$$L^1(\Bbb T)\subsetneq \mathcal R(\Bbb T)\subsetneq M(\Bbb T).$$
A characterization of Rajchmann's measure is given [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-10/issue-1/Characterizations-of-measures-whose-Fourier-Stieltjes-transforms-vanish-at-infinity/bams/1183551417.full)

Comment: In other words, this is defined as the class of measures for which Riemann--Lebesgue lemma remains true. :-)

Comment: I was mostly joking. Your references look useful. +1.

Comment: I agree with @GiuseppeNegro that defining the class in this way makes the answer somewhat tautological :) but many thanks for the reference, it's very interesting! Even just the fact that there exist singular measures belonging to this class, thus making it strictly larger than just $L^1$ densities, was not at all obvious to me!

Comment: @Lucio: this is connected to a major problem in Harmonic analysis, known as "restriction conjecture".

Comment: Continuing my previous comment: see eq. (7) of Tao notes on restriction: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2020/03/29/247b-notes-1-restriction-theory/

Comment: Very nice, thanks!